# Application's upper menu bar does not merge with the Panel when window is full size

Tags: unity, panel, menu-bar

Is anyone else having this problem on Ubuntu 16.04?

[image: here is a screenshot]

Comment: I have seen this before, and I think this is a bug with Chrome. Does restarting Chrome (by typing `chrome://restart` in the omnibox) help?

Comment: It happened with the "Videos" app that I had opened at the time too unfortunately. Yes, restarting the affected apps resolves the issue.

Comment: I see. I used to see this bug a couple releases ago and unfortunately I am unable to reproduce it reliably, so I didn't file a bug report. If you know how to reproduce the problem, I suggest filing a bug report at https://crbug.com.

Comment: It all happened when I tried to drag and drop a link from a google search and open it in another tab: for some reason the link was stuck to the mouse pointer and when I managed to release it the aforementioned bug happened. I don't know if I can reproduce it, right now all I have is this screenshot.